# timer.performWithDelay() - First Calling

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have a doubt about `timer.performWithDelay()`.

When I want to loop a function every set amount of time I adopt the normal formula

```
timer.performWithDelay( delay, function, 0 )
```

The function gets called after the delay value for the first time, and again every delay.  Is there any way to loop the same function without having to wait the first time?

Just to clarify:

EXECUTION -> delay -> EXECUTION -> delay -> EXECUTION -> delay (etc)

Instead of:

delay -> EXECUTION -> delay -> EXECUTION -> delay -> EXECUTION (etc)

Answer (score 8):

Why not explicitly call it first time (replacing `function`, which is a keyword, with `func`):

```
timer.performWithDelay( delay, func, 0 )
func()
```